# Build in travis CI

Tags: c++, cmake, travis-ci

There is a project. I want to do CI. I chose travis.
But I ran into some problems:

1. `cmake --build.`
   It's not working. He writes that there is no makefile. Although it is.
2. `cmake --build . --target package`
   with a team like that trying to get dep packages. But for some reason it requires the dependence of log4cplus.

Maybe someone has some ideas?

```
Run CPack packaging tool... CPack: Create package using STGZ CPack:
Install projects CPack: - Run preinstall target for: AppChat CPack: -
Install project: AppChat [] CMake Error at
/home/focus/Workspace/Development/AppChat/build/lib/libbacktrace/cmake_install.cmake:84
(file):   file INSTALL cannot find  
"/home/focus/Workspace/Development/AppChat/cmake/libbacktraceConfig.cmake":
No such file or directory. Call Stack (most recent call first):  
/home/focus/Workspace/Development/AppChat/build/cmake_install.cmake:52
(include)


CPack Error: Error when generating package: log4cplus Makefile:170:
recipe for target 'package' failed make: *** [package] Error 1
```

[my tavis file](https://github.com/k-morozov/AppChat/blob/deb_travis/.travis.yml)

[my cmake file](https://github.com/k-morozov/AppChat/blob/deb_travis/CMakeLists.txt)

[project](https://github.com/k-morozov/AppChat/tree/deb_travis)

Comment: please provide a [mre] within the question without relying on external links

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get the error message `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.` is that cmake does not create a Makefile as the `cmake ..` step already fails. The error message of the cmake step is at [this](https://travis-ci.org/github/k-morozov/AppChat/builds/712900016#L20141) where cmake mentions that it cannot find GTest. According to the article of https://david-grs.github.io/cpp-clang-travis-cmake-gtest-coveralls-appveyor/ installing gtest from the package repo as you do in your setup script will fail. As suggested there and also the way I use it is to include GTest as a submodule.

Comment: Thank you. I found another solution, gtest was installed at travis.yml.
do you have any ideas about deb packages? :)